# backbone.js / access view from model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I access the view from a model in backbone.js.

I would love to re-render the view on model.change().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding views to the model's attribute is a no-no.

Why would you need to access the view from model on its change?

In your view, simply bind:

```
this.model.bind('change', this.modelChanged, this) // (event, function, context)
```

and from now on, when your model changes, your view's `modelChanged` method will be called automatically.

---

in version [>0.9](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on), the proper syntax will be like this in the view.

```
this.model.on('change', this.modelChanged, this) // (event, function, context)
```

Comment: Thank you for the teaching :) If I do your code I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'change'. At http://www.ichbinadrian.ch/map/stackoverflow you can have a look at the code. I'm prototyping and learning :)

Comment: Try to debug what `this.view` returns. It's a large piece of code and it would be very helpful if you could narrow it to the essential parts.

Answer (score 1):

You may use one of two bindings:

```
this.model.bind('change', this.modelChanged)

this.model.bind('refresh', this.modelRefreshed)
```

Check the docs to see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There's another potential snafu to adding a `view` property to the model.  It's possible that a model might be represented by multiple views.  When this happens you'd have to change the `view` property to (an array) `views`.  That's harry coding.  I started off doing just this thing and realized my faux pas once I saw that multiple views could be involved.  I realized this was just another way of handling the publisher-subscriber pattern.

Others have been happy to have the model and view reference the other as a means of two-way communication. Gravel-Niquet does so in his [Todos](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) sample app.  Lerner suggests this in his June 2011 Linux Journal article on Backbone.js.  A matter of preference, perhaps, but I am with with pawlik.  Stick to events; that's what they're for.